# Creating a packet bytearray using a bytebuffer in Java

Tags: java, arrays, bytebuffer

How can I make a packet that is in the form of a byte[] in Java? I know that it should be done with a `ByteBuffer` and then I need to make it a byte[] and send it through a `DataOutputStream.`

Comment: Why not use the `ByteBuffer` itself and use a channel rather than a `DataOutputStream`? And why a `DataOutputStream`? Perhaps you should explain a little more about your assignment and its constraints.

Comment: @RealSkeptic if there's another way then please do let me know. I'm trying to send and receive the packets to a gameserver

Comment: Then you should expand your question and explain exactly what kind of packets the game server expects and in what protocol. You should also do some research and see if other people have already written code for that game server, or something with similar requirements, and you should read about sockets, channels and buffers.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make a packet that is in the form of a byte[] in Java? I know that it should be done with a `ByteBuffer` and then I need to make it a byte[] and send it through a `DataOutputStream.`

No, you don't know that. You *either:*

- Use a `ByteBuffer` and send it through a `Channel` directly, without an intermediate `byte[]`
- Use a `DataOutputStream` wrapped around a file or socket output stream, again without an intermediate `byte[]`
- use a `DataOutputStream` wrapped around a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, get the `byte[]` array from that, and send the `byte[]` array. This technique is unnecessary unless what you're trying to construct is a `DatagramPacket`.